# How do you code the responsive togglemenu?

Tags: jquery, css

On the desktop version, it will show the whole panel when its meet max-width:600px ( tablet and mobile size). It just show the title, and then when you click it, it will show the menu inner. If u resize the browser you can go back to desktop version and mobile version. I don't want to use a plugin.

I did try the desktop version, it works. I don't know how to make it responsive. When my breakpoint is 600px and I click on a different .menuCol h2 it will show and hide. When my breakpoint is larger than 600px ( when I resize my browser) some of the .menuList are hidden.

```js
function menuToggle() {
  $('#menuBtn').click(function() {
    var menuBtn = $('#menuBtn');
    var menuInner = $('.menuInner');

    if ($(menuInner).is(':hidden')) {
      $(menuBtn).text('close');
    } else {
      $(menuBtn).text('menu');
    }

    $(menuInner).fadeToggle(200);
  });
}

menuToggle();


function menuMobile() {
  $(".menuCol h2").click(function() {

    $(".menuList").slideUp();

    if (!$(this).next().is(":visible")) {
      $(this).next().slideDown();
    }
  });

}


menuMobile();
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-top: 80px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #434141;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
#toggleMenu {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#menuBtn {
  background-color: #fa7361;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #434141;
  padding: 2px 6px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.menuInner {
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #cce9ec;
  padding: 5%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.menuInner .menuCol {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  width: 22.5%;
  float: left;
}
.menuInner .menuCol h2 {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.menuInner li {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  margin-right: 3.3%;
}
.menuInner li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}
.menuList {
  display: block;
}
.menuList a:hover {
  color: #fa7361;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #fa7361;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .menuInner .menuCol {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .menuInner .menuCol h2 {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .menuInner .menuCol h2:hover {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fa7361;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #fa7361;
  }
  .menuCol:last-child h2 {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  .menuList {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="toggleMenu">
  <a id="menuBtn" href="#">menu</a>
  <ul class="menuInner">
    <li class="menuCol">
      <h2>Living Room</h2>
      <ul class="menuList">
        <li><a href="#">sofas & loveseats</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">chairs</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">benches</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">bookcases & shelving</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">all living room</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menuCol">
      <h2>Bedroom</h2>
      <ul class="menuList">
        <li><a href="#">beds</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">mattresses</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">daybeds & sleepers</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">floor mirrors</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">all bedroom</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menuCol">
      <h2>Home Office</h2>
      <ul class="menuList">
        <li><a href="#">desks</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">desk chairs</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">office storage</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">display ledges</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">all office</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menuCol">
      <h2>Dining Room</h2>
      <ul class="menuList">
        <li><a href="#">dining tables</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">dining chairs</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">bar & counter stools</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">dining benches</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">all dining</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Because you're using fixed widths.

Comment: can u help me with that? i know its my css problem.

Comment: i use a couple of hour to solve the problem but it doesnt work

Comment: In mobile you width should be 100% or something like that for `#toggleMenu`

Comment: i did put width 100%, but it doesn't work, why?